# RainbowKit does not work with MetaMask on iOS

Tags: metamask, walletconnect, wagmi, rainbowkit

#### Current Behavior

On iOS, when I tap "connect wallet", the "Connect a Wallet" overlay, I click "Metamask" and it directs me to the iOS App Store.

#### Expected Behavior

When I click "Metamask from the "Connect a Wallet" overlay, it should open Metamask

#### Steps To Reproduce

- Using the boilerplate project from the readme I ran `npm init @rainbow-me/rainbowkit@latest`
- Run the app with `npm run dev`
- Install ngrok (https://ngrok.com) (allows you to run the react app on your phone)
- run `./ngrok http 3000`
- Open the URL that ngrok generates for you
- tap "connect wallet"
- tap "metamask"

## Try it here (on an iOS device)

https://look-rainbowkit-doesnt-work.vercel.app/

#### Anything else?

In this issue: https://github.com/rainbow-me/rainbowkit/issues/634#issuecomment-1208830295 the following documentation is referenced: https://docs.walletconnect.com/mobile-linking#ios-app-link-constraints

But given that I'm using the boilerplate RainbowKit app, it seems like there shouldn't be any interfering network requests.

Am I missing something? Or does  MetaMask just not work out of the box with RainbowKit?

If it doesn't work, your docs should clearly address this.

Comment: You should report it as an issue to RainbowKit developers.